# HTML5 canvas sprite sheet random image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

At the moment the code chooses one image from the sprite sheet and displays it across the sreen, what I'd like to do is select random images across the row and display them in the game, for example I want red/pink/green asteroids to display but at the moment its just displaying the green ones.

This is the current code, any help would be fantastic.

```
function Enemy() {
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.width = 64;
    this.height = 64;
    this.previousSpeed = 0;
    this.speed = 2;
    this.acceleration = 0.005;
    this.drawX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + gameWidth;
    this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameHeight);
    this.collisionPointX = this.drawX + this.width;
    this.collisionPointY = this.drawY + this.height;
}

Enemy.prototype.draw = function () {
    this.drawX -= this.speed;
    ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
    this.checkEscaped();
};

Enemy.prototype.checkEscaped = function () {
    if (this.drawX + this.width <= 0) {
        this.recycleEnemy();
    }
};

Enemy.prototype.recycleEnemy = function () {
    this.drawX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + gameWidth;
    this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameHeight);
};

function clearCtxEnemy() {
    ctxEnemy.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to decide which image to use

> `function Enemy() {
>
>   ...
>
>   this.imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
>
>   ...
>
>   }`

When drawing use that variable to determine which image to use.

> `Enemy.prototype.draw = function () {
>
>   ...
>
>   ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX+this.imageNumber* this.width,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
>
>   ...
>
>   }`

Comment: You sir are a genius! 

I have another question, I have 3 rows with 1 row of asteroids 32 by 32, 2nd row 64 by 64 and final row 128 by 128. How would I also random the y axis?

Comment: @Nick You should post a new question (complete with code examples, like you did before).